# Create a list and filter results

Tags: html, list

I'm trying to create a basic search engine that filter results from a list, all in the same code, but it works only when the list has around 45-50 elements.

The code I'm using is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AHA</title>
<style>
    /* Stili CSS per la pagina */
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    input[type="text"] {
      padding: 5px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>AHA</h1>
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Cerca una parola...">
<ul id="resultsList">
 
</ul>
<script>
    // Funzione per filtrare la lista di testo in base alla parola cercata
    function filterResults() {
      var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
      var searchKeyword = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
      
      var resultsList = document.getElementById('resultsList');
      resultsList.innerHTML = ''; // Svuota la lista dei risultati
      
      // Itera sulla lista di righe di testo
      for (var i = 0; i < textData.length; i++) {
        var text = textData[i].toLowerCase();
        
        // Se la riga di testo contiene la parola cercata, aggiungi il risultato alla lista
        if (text.includes(searchKeyword)) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.textContent = textData[i];
          resultsList.appendChild(li);
        }
      }
    }
    
    // Evento per avviare il filtraggio quando si preme il tasto Invio
    var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) { // Codice tasto Invio
        filterResults();
      }
    });
    
    // Lista di righe di testo
    var textData = [
"-CA01-SARDEGNA IT, VIA DEI GIORNALISTI 6 - BADGE APRIPORTA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANCHE",
"-CA02-ENAS STABILI VIALE ELMAS 116 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CAO3-INPS SEDE VIA GRANDI 6 - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA04-INPS DIREZIONE REGIONALE VIALE DIAZ 35 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CAO5-INPS UFFICIO LEGALE VIA DELITALA 2 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA06-AREA, VIA CESARE BATTISTI 6 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA07-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI VIA MAZZINI 4 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA08-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI VIA MARENGO 13 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA09-UNICA CLINICA EX MACCIOTTA VIA OSPEDALE 119 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA10-UNICA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA VIA IS MIRRIONIS 1 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA11-UNICA BIBLIOTECA FACOLTA' ECONOMIA E GIURISPRUDENZA VIA SANT IGNAZIO 17 - N°5 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA12-ADER VIA ASPRONI 13/17 - N°9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA13-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BACCAREDDA, VIA GRANDI 9/11 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA14-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MICHELANGELO, VIA EFISIO MELIS/VIA SCHIAFFINO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA15-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DE SANCTIS DELEDDA, VIA CORNALIAS 169 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA16-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE TECNICO COMMERCIALE MARTINI, VIA CIUSA 4 - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA17-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE SIOTTO, VIALE TRENTO 103 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA18-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BUCCARI MARCONI, VIA VALERIO PISANO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA19-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE PACINOTTI, VIA BRIANZA 1 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA20-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE PACINOTTI, VIA LIGURIA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA21-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA CODROIPO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA22-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MICHELANGELO, VIA DEI DONORATICO/VIA CAPPELLINO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA23-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DE SANCTIS DELEDDA, VIA SULCIS - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA24-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA IS MAGLIAS 132 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA25-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE GIUA, VIA MONTECASSINO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA26-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERTI, VIALE COLOMBO 37 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA27-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ELEONORA D'ARBOREA, VIA CARBONI-BOI/ANGOLO VIA AMAT - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA28-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE EUCLIDE, VIA LIGAS + SUCCURSALE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA29-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ELEONORA D'ARBOREA, VIA S.CIVITA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA30-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERTI, VIA RAVENNA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA31-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DETTORI, VIA CUGIA 2 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA32-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA MONTE ACUTO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA33-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MEUCCI, VIA VESALIO 16 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA34-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE FOISO FOIS, VIA S.EUSEBIO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA35-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DETTORI, VIA ROLANDO",
"-CA36-UNICA FACOLTA' GIURISPRUDENZA, VIA SANT'INGNAZIO 78 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA37-UNICA FACOLTA' DI ARCHITETTURA, VIA CORTE D'APPELLO 87 - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA38-UNICA CENTRO DI CALCOLO, VIA UNIVERSITA' 40 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA39-UNICA ISTITUTO DI ZOOLOGIA PONTE VITTORIO, VIA FIORELLI - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA40-UNICA PALAZZO CUGIA, VIA SANTA CROCE 67 - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA41-UNICA CITTADELLA UNIVERSITARIA DI MONSERRATO CONTAMINATION LAB. AULA106 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO",
"-CA42-UNICA CLINICA ARESU, VIA SAN GIORGIO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA43-UNICA CENTRO LINGUISTICO D'ATENEO, VIA PORCEL - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA44-UNICA PALAZZO NIEDDU, VIA SANTA CROCE - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA45-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO SCIENZE TECNOLOGICHE BIOMETRIA IDENIX, Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
"-CA46-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO SANITA' PUBBLICA, VIA PORCEL - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA47-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO PSICOLOGIA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA48-UNICA BIBLIOTECA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA49-UNICA SEGRETERIA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA50-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.G, VIA MARENGO - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO - N°13 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
"-CA51-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.D, VIA MARENGO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA52-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.M, VIA MARENGO - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-CA53-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI, VIA MARENGO/VIALE MERELLO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA54-UNICA BIBLIOTECA FACOLTA' ECONOMIA E GIURISPRUDENZA, VIA SANT'IGNAZIO 17 - N°16 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA55-UNICA VIA SANT'IGNAZIO 76 - N°12CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-CA56-UNICA SEGRETERIA SCIENZE POLITICHE, VIA NICOLODI 104 - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME",
“-CA59-ENAS STABILI, VIALE ELMAS 116 - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA60-COOPSERVICE, VIA NERVI 09121- IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA61-FONDAZIONE SARDEGNA, VIA S SALVATORE DA HAORTA/VIA TORINO - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-CA62-AREA VIA FIRENZE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA63-SCANDELLARI, VIA DELL’ARTIGIANATO 4 - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA64-ENAS, VIA MAMELI 88 - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA65-ADER SANLURI, VIA MAZZINI 18 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-CA66-DOTT.PROTO, VIA DEI PUNICI - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA67-ISRE CITTADELLA DEI MUSEI COLLEZIONE LUIGI COCCO, PIAZZA ARSENALE - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME”,
“-CA68-AREA, LA PALMA, VIA EURO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA69-AREA, VIA CESARE BATTISTI - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME”,
“-CA70-ARPAS, VIALE CIUSA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA71-ARPAS, VIA CARLOFORTE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA72-ARPAS, VIA CONTIVECCHI - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 TARGHETTA CODICE INSERIMENTO/DISINSERIMENTO IMPIANTO ALLARME”,
“-CA73-IVG, LOC.SU PEZZU MANNU VIA DEL LAVORO SELARGIUS - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO”,
“-CA74-ARES DIREZIONE GENERALE, VIA PIERO DELLA FRANCESCA SELARGIUS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA75-ARES PO SS TRINITA’ INGRESSO TICKET - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-CA76-INAIL DIREZIONE REGIONALE, VIA SONNINO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA77-INAIL DIREZIONE PROVINCIALE, VIA TEMPIO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA78-INAIL, VIA NUORO 50/52 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA79-COMUNE DI ASSEMINI PALAZZO MUNICIPALE - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA80-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI SERVIZIO ECONOMATO E PATRIMONIO, VIALE TRIESTE 141 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA81-RAS ASSESSORATO LAVORO, VIA S.SIMONE - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA82-RAS PROTEZIONE CIVILE, VIA PARROCCHIA 190 VILLACIDRO - N° 2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA83-RAS CFVA, VIA BIASI 7 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA85-MEM ARMADIO DOTAZIONI, VIA MAMELI 164 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-CA86-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI UFFICIO URP, VIA N.SAURO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA87-RAS EX ASS.TO LAVORO, VIA XXVIII FEBBRAIO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA88-WIND TRE, VIALE MONASTIR KM6500 Z.I. ELMAS - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO N°00038074 - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
"-CA89-WIND TRE, VIA DEL LAVORO 34 SELARGIUS - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - ",
“-CA90-WIND TRE, LOCALITA’ PILL’E MATTA QUARTUCCIU - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA91-ELDOR CORPORATION, VIA DELLA TECNICA 12 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA93-ARGEA SANLURI,VIA GIOVANNI XXIII 3E SANLURI - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA94-RAS CORTE DEI CONTI, VIA ANGIUS 6 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA95-FILIALE UB254 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO”,
“-CA96-FILIALE UB SERRAMANNA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO”,
“-CA97-FILIALE UB CONFORAMA EX EMMEZETA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO”,
“-CA98-FILIALE UB, VIA CUGIA IN BUSTA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO”, 
“-CA99-ASPAL, VIA BORGO SANT’ELIA CAGLIARI”,
“-CA100-ISTITUTO PERTINI, VIA CARPACCIO N° 18 A - N° 1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-CA101-ATS DIREZIONE GENERALE, VIA PIERO DELLA FRANCESCA 1 - N° 3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-CA102-ARCAMONE ANTONIO, VIA PIERLUIGI DA PALESTRINA N°84 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO”,
“-CA106-ASL- DIREZIONE GENERALE SANLURI VIA UNGHERETTI N°9”,
“-QSE01-ITC LEONARDO DA VINCI MARTINI BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC MONSERRATO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSEO2-ITI LEVI INDUSTRIALE, PITZ’E SERRA LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
"-QSE03-ITC LEVI COMMERICIALE, PITZ'E SERRA, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE04-ISTITUTO ALBERGHIERO GRAMSCI, VIA DECIO MURE LOC.MONSERRATO - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 SPEZZATA","-QSEO5-LICEO CLASSICO MOTZO, VIA M.ANGIONI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE06-LICEO CLASSICO E LINGUISTICO MOTZO, VIA DON STURZO LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE07-LICEO CLASSICO E LINGUISTICO MOTZO, VIA MAGELLANO LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE08-LICEO SCIENTIFICO PITAGORA, VIA I MAGGIO LOC.SELARGIUS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE09-ISTITUTO TECNICO INDUSTRIALE SCANO, VIA CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE10-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE G.BROTZU LICEO ARTISTICO, VIA FADDA LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE", "-QSE11-ITC LICEO SCIENTIFICO BROTZU, VIA PITZ'E SERRA QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE12-LICEO FOISO FOIS BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE13-ITG BACCAREDDA-ATZENI, VIA BIXIO LOC.SELARGIUS - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE14-ITC LEONARDO DA VINCI-MARTINI-BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE15-POLITICHE SOCIALI, VIA CILEA 5 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE16-CANTIERE COMUNALE SA SERRIXEDDA QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE17-GLAREA CALCESTRUZZI SRL VIA P.ATTANASIO LOC.QUARTU S.ELENA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE18-EX MATTATOIO,QUARTU S.'ELENA, VIA DANTE 70 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE19-EX CONVENTO S.'AGATA, VIA BRIGATA SASSARI 35 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE20-EX CASA DEL PENSIONATO, VIA CILEA 36 QUARTU SANT'ELENA - N°10 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME",
"-QSE21-UFFICIO INFORMAZIONI, VIA MELIBODES - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE22-BIBLIOTECA VIA DANTE N°70,COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE23-ASILO NIDO, VIA DE CROSTIFORIS QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
"-QSE24-STAZIONE DI SOLLEVAMENTO, VIA DON GIORDI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE25-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA UFFICI VIA ROMA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
"-QSE26-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA EX CASERMA VIA ROMA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
"-QSE27-KARALIS SERVICE, VIA FLEMING LOC.SELARGIUS - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 TELECOMANDO CANCELLO AUTOMATICO",
“-QSE28-EI TOWER - N°10 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
"-QSE29-VODAFONE IT, VIA FLEMING LOC.SELARGIUS - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO CODICE VIGILANZA Z3 - ",
“-QSE30-GLS SESTU - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE31-ASPAL CAPANNONE Z.I. QUARTU S.ELENA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-QSE32-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA SA DOMU E FARRA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE33-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA EX LUDOTECA VIA REGINA ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE34-UNICA CAMPUS VIA FIORELLI LOC.CAGLIARI - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE35-CC LE VELE GALLERIA MILLENNIUM LOC.QUARTUCCIU - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELLETTORE ALLARME”, 
“-QSE101-OVS COMUNE DI QUARTUCCIU,VIA DELLE SERRE - N° 9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO -RITIRO IN UFFICIO”,
“-QSE103-VIA DELLE SERRE THE SPACE CINEMA - IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO - RITIRO IN UFFICIO N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE104-VIA BIZET N°27, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-QSE105-EX MONTE GRANATICA VIA XX SETTEMBRE 21, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N° 1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-UTO1-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE GIUA + PALESTRA, VIA BACCAREDDA LOC.ASSEMINI - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-UTO2-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BACCAREDDA-ATZENI, VIA TREXENTA LOC.CAPOTERRA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-UT03-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DUCA DEGLI ABRUZZI, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-UT04-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERGHIERO AZUNI, VIA NORA LOC.PULA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-UTO5-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ENRICO MATTEI, VIA UGO FOSCOLO LOC.ELMAS - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
"-UT06-LOMBARDA COSTRUZIONI, 7°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE ",
“-UT07-GLS ASSEMINI - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
"-UT08-STABILIMENTO NIVEA EX LISAR, 2°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE ",
“-UT09-STABILIMENTO NIVEA, 5°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-UT10-STABILIMENTO NIVEA EX DEMI, 10°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”,
“-UT11-STABILIMENTI NIVEA, AUTOMATISMO INGRESSI CARRAI - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO N°091”,
“-UT12-CALCESTRUZZI SRL, GLAREA SRL, SS130 KM 17,600 S.N.C. LOC.UTA - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-UT13-STAZIONE FS CAGLIARI - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE”,
“-UT14-TERRANOVA CORTEXANDRA LOC.SESTU - N°1 CHIAVE”,
“-UT15-ISTITUTO ZOOPROFILATTICO ELMAS, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME”,
“-UT16-RAS EX CIFDA, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 CIALDA IMPIANTO D’ALLARME”,
“-UT17-MAGAZZINO TEATRO LIRICO CAGLIARI, Z.I. ELMAS - N°14 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 CIALDA INSERIMENTO IMPIANTO D’ALLARME”,
“-UT18-VERDE VITA, SS195 KM14300 LOC.CAPOTERRA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA”
    ];
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason why the code is working only up to 50 elements on the list and not further?
I am not a html or any markup language, I'm trying to do this personal utility i'll use to facilitate my job, so i would prefer not to make things tough ( for me at least ) using databases and things like that. If i can solve in a single html file, It would be amazing for me.

Comment: What happens when it's more than 50 elements?

Comment: As I check with your code, it seems that there is a problem with your data. There's no problem with the function just correct your data. I thinks that it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as saying Newbee it's a problem with your data.

seems you're italian, as in french in langage you can have 2 different double quotes, entry and end.

in your data :
from -CA59 to -CA88, -CA90 to -QSE03 and (... several other places) bad "

replace your textData by this one, it's working

```
// Lista di righe di testo
    var textData = [
        "-CA01-SARDEGNA IT, VIA DEI GIORNALISTI 6 - BADGE APRIPORTA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANCHE",
        "-CA02-ENAS STABILI VIALE ELMAS 116 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CAO3-INPS SEDE VIA GRANDI 6 - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA04-INPS DIREZIONE REGIONALE VIALE DIAZ 35 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CAO5-INPS UFFICIO LEGALE VIA DELITALA 2 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA06-AREA, VIA CESARE BATTISTI 6 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA07-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI VIA MAZZINI 4 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA08-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI VIA MARENGO 13 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA09-UNICA CLINICA EX MACCIOTTA VIA OSPEDALE 119 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA10-UNICA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA VIA IS MIRRIONIS 1 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA11-UNICA BIBLIOTECA FACOLTA' ECONOMIA E GIURISPRUDENZA VIA SANT IGNAZIO 17 - N°5 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA12-ADER VIA ASPRONI 13/17 - N°9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA13-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BACCAREDDA, VIA GRANDI 9/11 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA14-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MICHELANGELO, VIA EFISIO MELIS/VIA SCHIAFFINO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA15-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DE SANCTIS DELEDDA, VIA CORNALIAS 169 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA16-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE TECNICO COMMERCIALE MARTINI, VIA CIUSA 4 - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA17-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE SIOTTO, VIALE TRENTO 103 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA18-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BUCCARI MARCONI, VIA VALERIO PISANO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA19-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE PACINOTTI, VIA BRIANZA 1 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA20-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE PACINOTTI, VIA LIGURIA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA21-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA CODROIPO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA22-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MICHELANGELO, VIA DEI DONORATICO/VIA CAPPELLINO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA23-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DE SANCTIS DELEDDA, VIA SULCIS - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA24-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA IS MAGLIAS 132 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA25-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE GIUA, VIA MONTECASSINO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA26-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERTI, VIALE COLOMBO 37 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA27-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ELEONORA D'ARBOREA, VIA CARBONI-BOI/ANGOLO VIA AMAT - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA28-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE EUCLIDE, VIA LIGAS + SUCCURSALE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA29-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ELEONORA D'ARBOREA, VIA S.CIVITA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA30-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERTI, VIA RAVENNA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA31-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DETTORI, VIA CUGIA 2 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA32-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE AZUNI, VIA MONTE ACUTO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA33-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE MEUCCI, VIA VESALIO 16 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA34-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE FOISO FOIS, VIA S.EUSEBIO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA35-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DETTORI, VIA ROLANDO",
        "-CA36-UNICA FACOLTA' GIURISPRUDENZA, VIA SANT'INGNAZIO 78 - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA37-UNICA FACOLTA' DI ARCHITETTURA, VIA CORTE D'APPELLO 87 - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA38-UNICA CENTRO DI CALCOLO, VIA UNIVERSITA' 40 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA39-UNICA ISTITUTO DI ZOOLOGIA PONTE VITTORIO, VIA FIORELLI - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA40-UNICA PALAZZO CUGIA, VIA SANTA CROCE 67 - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA41-UNICA CITTADELLA UNIVERSITARIA DI MONSERRATO CONTAMINATION LAB. AULA106 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO",
        "-CA42-UNICA CLINICA ARESU, VIA SAN GIORGIO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA43-UNICA CENTRO LINGUISTICO D'ATENEO, VIA PORCEL - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA44-UNICA PALAZZO NIEDDU, VIA SANTA CROCE - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA45-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO SCIENZE TECNOLOGICHE BIOMETRIA IDENIX, Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-CA46-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO SANITA' PUBBLICA, VIA PORCEL - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA47-UNICA DIPARTIMENTO PSICOLOGIA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA48-UNICA BIBLIOTECA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA49-UNICA SEGRETERIA CAMPUS SA DUCHESSA, VIA IS MIRRIONIS - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA50-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.G, VIA MARENGO - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO - N°13 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-CA51-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.D, VIA MARENGO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA52-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI PAD.M, VIA MARENGO - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA53-UNICA CAMPUS PIAZZA D'ARMI, VIA MARENGO/VIALE MERELLO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA54-UNICA BIBLIOTECA FACOLTA' ECONOMIA E GIURISPRUDENZA, VIA SANT'IGNAZIO 17 - N°16 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA55-UNICA VIA SANT'IGNAZIO 76 - N°12CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA56-UNICA SEGRETERIA SCIENZE POLITICHE, VIA NICOLODI 104 - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME",
        "-CA59-ENAS STABILI, VIALE ELMAS 116 - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA59-ENAS STABILI, VIALE ELMAS 116 - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA60-COOPSERVICE, VIA NERVI 09121- IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA61-FONDAZIONE SARDEGNA, VIA S SALVATORE DA HAORTA/VIA TORINO - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA62-AREA VIA FIRENZE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA63-SCANDELLARI, VIA DELL’ARTIGIANATO 4 - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA64-ENAS, VIA MAMELI 88 - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA65-ADER SANLURI, VIA MAZZINI 18 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA66-DOTT.PROTO, VIA DEI PUNICI - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA67-ISRE CITTADELLA DEI MUSEI COLLEZIONE LUIGI COCCO, PIAZZA ARSENALE - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-CA68-AREA, LA PALMA, VIA EURO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA69-AREA, VIA CESARE BATTISTI - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-CA70-ARPAS, VIALE CIUSA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA71-ARPAS, VIA CARLOFORTE - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA72-ARPAS, VIA CONTIVECCHI - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 TARGHETTA CODICE INSERIMENTO/DISINSERIMENTO IMPIANTO ALLARME",
        "-CA73-IVG, LOC.SU PEZZU MANNU VIA DEL LAVORO SELARGIUS - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-CA74-ARES DIREZIONE GENERALE, VIA PIERO DELLA FRANCESCA SELARGIUS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA75-ARES PO SS TRINITA’ INGRESSO TICKET - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA76-INAIL DIREZIONE REGIONALE, VIA SONNINO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA77-INAIL DIREZIONE PROVINCIALE, VIA TEMPIO - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA78-INAIL, VIA NUORO 50/52 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA79-COMUNE DI ASSEMINI PALAZZO MUNICIPALE - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA80-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI SERVIZIO ECONOMATO E PATRIMONIO, VIALE TRIESTE 141 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA81-RAS ASSESSORATO LAVORO, VIA S.SIMONE - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA82-RAS PROTEZIONE CIVILE, VIA PARROCCHIA 190 VILLACIDRO - N° 2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA83-RAS CFVA, VIA BIASI 7 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA85-MEM ARMADIO DOTAZIONI, VIA MAMELI 164 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA86-COMUNE DI CAGLIARI UFFICIO URP, VIA N.SAURO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA87-RAS EX ASS.TO LAVORO, VIA XXVIII FEBBRAIO - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA88-WIND TRE, VIALE MONASTIR KM6500 Z.I. ELMAS - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO N°00038074 - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA89-WIND TRE, VIA DEL LAVORO 34 SELARGIUS - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - ",
        "-CA90-WIND TRE, LOCALITA’ PILL’E MATTA QUARTUCCIU - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA91-ELDOR CORPORATION, VIA DELLA TECNICA 12 - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA93-ARGEA SANLURI,VIA GIOVANNI XXIII 3E SANLURI - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA94-RAS CORTE DEI CONTI, VIA ANGIUS 6 - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA95-FILIALE UB254 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-CA96-FILIALE UB SERRAMANNA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-CA97-FILIALE UB CONFORAMA EX EMMEZETA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-CA98-FILIALE UB, VIA CUGIA IN BUSTA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO-RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-CA99-ASPAL, VIA BORGO SANT’ELIA CAGLIARI",
        "-CA100-ISTITUTO PERTINI, VIA CARPACCIO N° 18 A - N° 1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-CA101-ATS DIREZIONE GENERALE, VIA PIERO DELLA FRANCESCA 1 - N° 3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-CA102-ARCAMONE ANTONIO, VIA PIERLUIGI DA PALESTRINA N°84 - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO",
        "-CA106-ASL- DIREZIONE GENERALE SANLURI VIA UNGHERETTI N°9",
        "-QSE01-ITC LEONARDO DA VINCI MARTINI BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC MONSERRATO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSEO2-ITI LEVI INDUSTRIALE, PITZ’E SERRA LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE03-ITC LEVI COMMERICIALE, PITZ'E SERRA, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE04-ISTITUTO ALBERGHIERO GRAMSCI, VIA DECIO MURE LOC.MONSERRATO - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 SPEZZATA", "-QSEO5-LICEO CLASSICO MOTZO, VIA M.ANGIONI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE06-LICEO CLASSICO E LINGUISTICO MOTZO, VIA DON STURZO LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE07-LICEO CLASSICO E LINGUISTICO MOTZO, VIA MAGELLANO LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE08-LICEO SCIENTIFICO PITAGORA, VIA I MAGGIO LOC.SELARGIUS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE09-ISTITUTO TECNICO INDUSTRIALE SCANO, VIA CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE10-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE G.BROTZU LICEO ARTISTICO, VIA FADDA LOC.QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE", "-QSE11-ITC LICEO SCIENTIFICO BROTZU, VIA PITZ'E SERRA QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE12-LICEO FOISO FOIS BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE13-ITG BACCAREDDA-ATZENI, VIA BIXIO LOC.SELARGIUS - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE14-ITC LEONARDO DA VINCI-MARTINI-BESTA, VIA CESARE CABRAS LOC.MONSERRATO - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE15-POLITICHE SOCIALI, VIA CILEA 5 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE16-CANTIERE COMUNALE SA SERRIXEDDA QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE17-GLAREA CALCESTRUZZI SRL VIA P.ATTANASIO LOC.QUARTU S.ELENA - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE18-EX MATTATOIO,QUARTU S.'ELENA, VIA DANTE 70 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE19-EX CONVENTO S.'AGATA, VIA BRIGATA SASSARI 35 QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°6 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE20-EX CASA DEL PENSIONATO, VIA CILEA 36 QUARTU SANT'ELENA - N°10 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°2 SELETTORI ALLARME",
        "-QSE21-UFFICIO INFORMAZIONI, VIA MELIBODES - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE22-BIBLIOTECA VIA DANTE N°70,COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE23-ASILO NIDO, VIA DE CROSTIFORIS QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-QSE24-STAZIONE DI SOLLEVAMENTO, VIA DON GIORDI QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE25-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA UFFICI VIA ROMA - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE26-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA EX CASERMA VIA ROMA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-QSE27-KARALIS SERVICE, VIA FLEMING LOC.SELARGIUS - N°7 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 TELECOMANDO CANCELLO AUTOMATICO",
        "-QSE28-EI TOWER - N°10 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE29-VODAFONE IT, VIA FLEMING LOC.SELARGIUS - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO CODICE VIGILANZA Z3 - ",
        "-QSE30-GLS SESTU - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE31-ASPAL CAPANNONE Z.I. QUARTU S.ELENA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-QSE32-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA SA DOMU E FARRA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE33-COMUNE DI QUARTU S.'ELENA EX LUDOTECA VIA REGINA ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE34-UNICA CAMPUS VIA FIORELLI LOC.CAGLIARI - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE35-CC LE VELE GALLERIA MILLENNIUM LOC.QUARTUCCIU - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELLETTORE ALLARME",
        "-QSE101-OVS COMUNE DI QUARTUCCIU,VIA DELLE SERRE - N° 9 CHIAVI MECCANICHE IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO -RITIRO IN UFFICIO",
        "-QSE103-VIA DELLE SERRE THE SPACE CINEMA - IN BUSTA ANTISABOTAGGIO - RITIRO IN UFFICIO N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE104-VIA BIZET N°27, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-QSE105-EX MONTE GRANATICA VIA XX SETTEMBRE 21, QUARTU S.'ELENA - N° 1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-UTO1-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE GIUA + PALESTRA, VIA BACCAREDDA LOC.ASSEMINI - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UTO2-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE BACCAREDDA-ATZENI, VIA TREXENTA LOC.CAPOTERRA - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UT03-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE DUCA DEGLI ABRUZZI, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-UT04-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ALBERGHIERO AZUNI, VIA NORA LOC.PULA - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UTO5-ISTITUTO SUPERIORE ENRICO MATTEI, VIA UGO FOSCOLO LOC.ELMAS - N°5 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UT06-LOMBARDA COSTRUZIONI, 7°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°4 CHIAVI MECCANICHE ",
        "-UT07-GLS ASSEMINI - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-UT08-STABILIMENTO NIVEA EX LISAR, 2°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°2 CHIAVI MECCANICHE ",
        "-UT09-STABILIMENTO NIVEA, 5°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-UT10-STABILIMENTO NIVEA EX DEMI, 10°STRADA Z.I. MACCHIAREDDU - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA",
        "-UT11-STABILIMENTI NIVEA, AUTOMATISMO INGRESSI CARRAI - N°1 BADGE ELETTRONICO N°091",
        "-UT12-CALCESTRUZZI SRL, GLAREA SRL, SS130 KM 17,600 S.N.C. LOC.UTA - N°8 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UT13-STAZIONE FS CAGLIARI - N°12 CHIAVI MECCANICHE",
        "-UT14-TERRANOVA CORTEXANDRA LOC.SESTU - N°1 CHIAVE",
        "-UT15-ISTITUTO ZOOPROFILATTICO ELMAS, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE - N°1 SELETTORE ALLARME",
        "-UT16-RAS EX CIFDA, VIA DELL’ACQUEDOTTO ROMANO LOC.ELMAS - N°3 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 CIALDA IMPIANTO D’ALLARME",
        "-UT17-MAGAZZINO TEATRO LIRICO CAGLIARI, Z.I. ELMAS - N°14 CHIAVI MECCANICHE + 1 CIALDA INSERIMENTO IMPIANTO D’ALLARME",
        "-UT18-VERDE VITA, SS195 KM14300 LOC.CAPOTERRA - N°1 CHIAVE MECCANICA"
    ];
```